# Misra-C Violation: Malformed for-loop condition

Tags: c, misra

I'm not sure, why Misra-C report this error in the below snap of the code.

```
int count = 0;
element = TAILQ_LAST(&(phdata->ph_consice_head), phqueue);

for (;
        element; // Malformed for-loop Condition help
                    The termination clause of this for loop is not of the expected form. 
        element = TAILQ_PREV(element, phqueue, next)) {
    count ++;
}
```

**Note** - element is pointer to a struct.

If someone can help me to figure out what's wrong with the for-loop that would be appreciable.

Comment: Well, why did you assign the initial value of `element` *outside* the loop syntax? While syntactically correct, please use the syntax the way it is intended

Comment: I am not familiar with MISRA rules, but have you tried changing `element;` to `element != NULL;`?

Comment: Messages from MISRA checkers should cite MISRA rules. What rule was cited in the error message you received? When asking questions of this nature, you should show the complete exact text of the message.

Comment: You have to remember that MISRA is more of a style guide than anything else, so when you differ from what they consider good style you get a notification like in this case. Sometimes it is annoying.

Comment: @AndersK MISRA C is explicitly _not_ a style guide. It may sometimes seem that way, but all rules seek to prevent potentially dangerous code. For example complex `for` loops messing around with multiple side effects and changing the loop iterator all over the place have a huge potential for bugs.

Comment: @Lundin isn't that a style guide what you are describing? it enforces that the code looks in a certain way. With the added benefit of reducing the number of potential bugs.

Comment: @AndersK: “Style” is commonly used with a connotation of aesthetic purpose, whereas MISRA is intended to be functional; it is intended to prescribe forms to use for the purpose of reducing errors. However, this connotation may be inapt. In writing for example, people may promote Strunk and White’s style, and people may prefer this aesthetically for reading or writing or both, but it does have a functional purpose, of improving communication. “Style” means a manner of doing something, so MISRA is in fact a style guide.

Comment: @AndersK In this context coding style refers to things like indention depth, brace placement, where to place extra spaces and other subjective things. It's important to make distinction between "coding style" (subjective) and "coding guidelines", because when MISRA for example says that you must always use `{ }` after every control or loop statement, it isn't because they think it looks prettier, but because failing to do so is a known safety hazard.

Comment: In the context of klocwork and pclint - static code analsis tools that I use, MISRA is a set of rules that judge the style so that to avoid common mistakes a programmer can do. In that context it is a style guide, even in the MISRA doc itself they call it guidelines. But I guess we will just have to agree to disagree as it is no point in arguing about this.

Comment: I remember now why I don't like SO any longer. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: What you are describing is a simple ``while`` loop rather than a ``for`` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MISRA C:2012 rule 14.2 is pretty self-explanatory regarding what it allows in the respective 3 clauses of a `for` loop. Like with any rule, you need to study it before you can use MISRA C.

In this case the 2nd clause needs to use the loop iterator and the static analyser might be a bit confused regarding what to consider as the loop iterator here.

Furthermore `element;` is non-compliant against MISRA 14.4, you need to explicitly make an "essentially boolean" expression such as `element != NULL`.

For MISRA compliance I would recommend a rewrite like this:

```
element = TAILQ_LAST(&(phdata->ph_consice_head), phqueue);

for (int count = 0; ; count++)
{
  if(element == NULL)
  {
    break;
  }
  element = TAILQ_PREV(element, phqueue, next);
}
```

Alternatively you could also make the 2nd clause `count<n` if there is some known maximum number of iterations.

Comment: (Please note that for pure MISRA compliance you should also switch to stdint.h types `uint32_t count = 0u;`)

Answer (score 2):

MISRA is very much a creature of habits and does not like anything "looking unusual".
It likes `for` loops best as in

```
for(something=value;
    boolean_expression /* ideally something<size */;
    incremental_change /* ideally something++)
```

Comment: This is an over-simplification, there are lots of rules regarding how one is allowed to write a for loop. Making the 2nd clause boolean doesn't fix all problems.

Comment: @Lundin True. This answer matches the level of details provided by OP. And it does address what to me seems to be the question behind the question "Why is there a MISRA violation if it is syntactically allowed and functionally works?". And the common part of many to most MISRA rules is in my opinion indeed "looks unusual". Pointing that out I always perceived to actually be the history and goal of MISRA, as somebody who actually has to minimise MISRA violations for making my money.

Comment: I don't really need to know which rules the tool whined about to tell which parts that are MISRA violations though. But then I've done quite a few MISRA C code reviews over the years. Turns out that MISRA C and veteran C programmers both like for loops to look as simple and idiomatic as possible. One may always apply the classic code quality metric [WTF/minute](https://i.redd.it/btd5aebzr5h01.jpg) :)

Comment: I think we agree. Great great diagram/illustration. While MISRA itself (in contrast to the code it complains about) gets a lot of WTFs by (not necessarily younger) colleagues, the basic state of mind matches mine. @Lundin Once you see, in a review, code lines commented out (in contrast to being replaced by functionally identical, MISRA-conforming code) with reasoning "avoid MISRA violation" you also understand the darkest side of quality processes.

Comment: Ironically, "commenting out" code is a MISRA violation in itself. Practical experience of using MISRA C is that you should make company-wide rules in a document, where allowed deviations are listed. Then you set up everyone's static analyser to ignore those rules. And from there individual developers are not allowed to deviate. This has many benefits: 1) individual deviations is a pain in the neck to administrate, 2) not every dev is qualified to make the call when to deviate, they might not understand a specific rule, 3) everyone is using the same style, 4) encourage learning over ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops are best used for a know number of iterations; `while` loops make much more sense for situations like this:

What your code shows is a `while` loop, rather than a `for` loop... it could be shown much more clearly (and be MISRA compliant) as:

```
int count = 0;
element = TAILQ_LAST( &(phdata->ph_consice_head), phqueue );

while ( element != NULL )
{
  count++;
  element = TAILQ_LAST( &(phdata->ph_consice_head), phqueue );
}
```

Posting in a personal capacity.